# antivowel program using nested for loops

Tags: python

Hello I am stuck on understanding this antivowel code for an exercise in Codecademy

```
1) # Here is the code 
2) vowels="aeiou" 
3) def anti_vowel(x):
4)     for a in x:     
5)         for j in vowels: 
6)            if a.lower()==j:
7)                x=x.replace(a,"")
8)     return x
```

why does the .lower function need to be set to x in line 7? When using functions do we always have to set it to a variable if we want to call the function?

also, in line 4 to 5 is this considered as a nested for loop?

Comment: because `.replace()` RETURNS the  modified string. it doesn't update the old string for you.

Answer (score 2):

`.replace(<string>)` returns a modified string. Normally, we could set it equal to a new variable. But the programmer chose to overwrite the old variable `x` with the new modified string. 
It is similar to saying `x = x + 1`. You are modifying the old string, but instead of saving it to a new variable, the programmer chose to update the variable. 
You do not have to always set a variable, but if the function returns a value it is recommended (or append it to a list or something). What is the point of calling a function if you are not going to set the return to something?

You don't have to if you are using it in a conditional. For example (this could be done in a simpler way, but FOR THE PURPOSE OF THE EXAMPLE):

`x = raw_input("Please input a number\n")`

The number is then stored as x.

If you want to compare the number to another value, you can call the function `int()` within the conditional instead of setting it as another variable.

```
if int(x) == 5:
    print 'Yay, you guessed right!'
```

The alternative:

```
y = int(x)
if y == 5:
    print 'Yay, you guessed right!'
```

Hope this helps!

Happy coding, and best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In Python there is an important difference between methods that are *in place*, meaning they modify the object they are being called upon, and methods that are not in-place and instead *return* a new object.

So in your example `x.replace(a,"")` *returns* a new string. It does not modify the original string `x`.